# How to include custom data files in ClickOnce deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

Is it possible to include custom data files in **ClickOnce** deployment?

I couldn't find any option for this (Visual Studio 2005 and 2010). The **Application Files** dialog from the **publish** tab just doesn't show custom files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible. From *ClickOnce Deployment Overview* in *[ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28VS.80%29.aspx)* (MSDN):

> **Installation of shared files** --  **No**

Also the article *[ClickOnce deployment or not?](http://coffeedrivendevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/09/clickonce-deployment-or-not.html)* was very useful.

Comment: ClickOnce deployment scheme is marvellous and great, because it is so straightforward. what I got stuck with actually was trying to package a custom XSD file that was a part of one DLL (part of that project) with another DLL that referenced the first DLL. - finally I did this as suggested somewhere here, plainly including the XSD into the second project as well - it looks like a not-so-coherent solution, and not very sustainable. Even then I had problems because the change in the project files was not immediately reflected (not sure how..) in the new publish I did.. used MageUI for debugging

Comment: It is ***not*** impossible (that is, it ***is*** possible). See [aL3891's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414823/how-to-include-custom-data-files-in-clickonce-deployment/12706531#12706531). It even works using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 6):

It actually possible, at least as of Visual Studio 2012 (most likely Visual Studio 2010 as well). The key is to set the build action on the file to "Content".

More information is in *[Custom Folders in ClickOnce](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/7feeb7ba-0262-44da-a11b-09035a54dfb8/)*.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of property "Copy to Output Directory" be changed to "Copy always" (from, say, "Do not copy")?

Comment: Provided property "Copy to Output Directory" was set to "Copy always", it worked for me today without any problems for the ClickOnce application I am working on (Visual Studio 2008 (don't ask)), including deploying the ClickOnce application to an external HTTP server and accepting the updating offer on a client machine.