# Embed individualized code into ClickOnce setup.exe?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I know that it is possible to pass in parameters via URL to ClickOnce apps launched online.  However, most users downloads setup.exe and launch it from their machine. Is there any way that I can re-write setup.exe at download, insert a code (let's say the user's email address), and then have the app launch with knowledge of the code? Assume that we can somehow re-sign setup.exe so that it is legit.

Assume .NET 3.5.

**Update** The goal here is to pass on either email address and/or referrer information to setup.exe so that even when the user runs the installer from a different machine and a different ip we can figure out who did the referral.

**Update 2** Assume .NET 3.5 SP1, does it help? Apparently one can now pass parameters to .application while offline. Is it possible to embed parameters into the setup.exe so that it calls .application?ref=someone right when setup.exe is run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if your goal is to embed a customer id (email, code, etc) into the exe, the easiest way I can think of is using the [IPropertyStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IPropertySetStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces.  If you are feeling brave, you could call methods directly on IPropertySetStorage via [p/invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IPropertySetStorage.html), or you could go the easy route and use Microsoft's prepared COM wrapper, which is called [dsofile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351).

Note that while dsofile is intended for office documents, it does indeed work on any file - including .exe files - you are just stuck with the pre-defined property names.  Why not throw your customer id into something like the .Comments property. Just do it in such a way that you can parse it out again.

Here's a sample:

```
var doc = new OleDocumentPropertiesClass();
doc.Open(pathToFile);
doc.SummaryProperties.Comments = "joe@test.com";
doc.Save();
```

Of course, you need to first copy it to a temp location, and some time after the user downloads it you'll want to delete it.

You can bundle dsofile.dll with your application and register it as a dependancy and use it in your installer to read the property back out.  Or if you can p/invoke the IPropertyStorage without it, then you won't have the dependancy.

The other thing to look into would be using the extended file properties that are read by the Shell32.dll.  I just haven't been able to find a clean way to write them easily.  If you go this route, please share how you wrote the properties to your .exe.

Comment: That is a truly innovative idea. I like that. Do you know if I can determine the setup.exe file used to install a .application?

Comment: The idea would be to use the data during installation itself, so it would be the image file of the running process.  Now, I don't really do much with ClickOnce, so I can't be certain how you might do it at install time.  If this was a regular MSI, you'd implement it as a custom action.  I use WiX to author MSI for my installations.  ClickOnce is nice, but can be limiting.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look whether InPlaceHostingManager class can help you in this case. It won't probably do exactly what you have asked for. But may be able to help...

> Any ClickOnce application based on an .exe file can be silently
>   installed and updated by a custom installer. A custom installer can
>   implement custom user experience during installation, including custom
>   dialog boxes for security and maintenance operations. To perform
>   installation operations, the custom installer uses the
>   [InPlaceHostingManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.inplacehostingmanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class.

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for a ClickOnce Application](http://jasper-net.blogspot.com/2011/03/walkthrough-creating-custom-installer.html)

**EDIT**

I am not sure whether you could achieve what you want exactly in the way that you have described in the question. Check whether these threads help you.

[Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[How to include custom data files in ClickOnce deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414823/how-to-include-custom-data-files-in-clickonce-deployment)

[How to: Retrieve Query String Information in an Online ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx)

Comment: Hi CharithJ, thanks for the proposal, but I don't see how I can make it do what I want. The goal is actually to embed referral information into the setup.exe so that even if they download and run setup.exe later (even from a different ip address) I can track who referred the download.

Comment: Do you really want to write the referral information to the setup? How about writing the referral information to the registory or some config file and read that when run the setup?

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I guess in that case setup.exe might be delivered in a zip file so that when they run it, it will read the config file that is packaged with the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

How would you imagine to "rewrite" setup.exe at download? if instead of opening your application with the provided link (url) users are downloading the file locally directly from the network share, you can't intercept this.

I would try to play with permissions and have the users to execute it from the link provided to them, but unable to connect directly to the share or web address and download it. Not sure this is possible anyway.

Comment: Instead of a real setup.exe, the webhost would direct the setup.exe to a script which modifies the setup.exe and delivers the bits to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try embedding that information as a resource into the exe.
Here's a c++ example of updating a resource of an exe. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources

Comment: This exe is created by ClickOnce to deploy the .NET application.

Comment: You should be able to modify any exe's resource table, if you create it or not. Additionally you could create a launcher exe, that has the clickonce exe as a resource and the user's info as a resource. Then when that runs unpack and run the clickonce and then your app can get the resource from the launcher

Answer (score 0):

You should combine approach by Charith and Josh - essentially, configure your web server so that you can generate a new setup based on URL parameters. Use custom installer to read from the referral information from resource for setup.exe. Check [this link](http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-add-resources-to-native-executable-file-with-updateresource/) for how to manipulate resources for a native application in C# - you have to write to resource file while generating setup and need to read it from your custom installer.

Yet another way of generating custom setup would be to build your executable or helper assemblt from command line  embedding the necessary information. And then build the setup from command line tools (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx). It appears to be quite cumbersome and will take long time to generate the custom setup as opposed to modifying the resource of already built setup.

A completely different approach would be to email the unique referral code (registration code) whenever user downloads the application. In the setup (or application), use custom installer to prompt user for this code. If the setup is invoked via URL then the code will be available from there and in such case Custom Installer need not ask for the code. The email that you send when user download the setup should inform user to preseve the code into some text file along with the setup file.

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for the suggestion. In fact the current solution is to email the user a code. However, I think we can do better than that.